# azure custom domain with SSL denying connection

Tags: azure, ssl

I am attempting to add ssl to my custom domain for the windows azure websites. I have configured everything properly according to the guides, but for an unknown reason when I attempt to access my website via HTTPS, it returns with a connection denied error. the redirect still works perfectly fine with a standard HTTP request.

for reference (https://www.cryptoalias.io)

short version of method (in case I missed something):

bought a SSL cert from comodo.com

generated a .pfx from the .cer they issued to me (using iis)

uploaded .pfx to azure

verified cname: created custom domain redirect to azure

bound ssl to custom domain

configured A name redirect to the VIP azure issued me. remove cname redirect

attempt to connect to https = nothing, http works.

sorry I realize this is rather short on information, but I'm not sure what more I could provide besides the actual SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your cert on 2 domains: `cryptoalias.io` and `www.cryptoalias.io`. Because if you go to `https://cryptoalias.io/` your cert works fine.